# Getting error while adding scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, to the listview builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting an error while adding `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` to the `ListView` builder of my `ListView`.

The application crashes.

```dart
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: _users == null || _users!.isEmpty
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              itemCount: _users.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int i) {
                return new Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(_users[i].name.toString()),
                      ListView.builder(
                        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        primary: false,
                        itemCount: _users[i].chart.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int j) {
                          return Text(_users[i]
                              .chart[j]
                              .ch_timestamp); // display username as an example
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
    );
```

Comment: Where's your error message?

Comment: Also crash must be because of some other issue and not horizontal listview. is it in row?

Comment: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
Assertion failed: file:///C:/Users/amirh/Downloads/Compressed/flutter_windows_3.7.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:2009:12
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#967a0 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE"

Comment: Please post full code

Comment: editet code pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have is that you are trying to add horizontal scrolling to a `ListView` that its default is vertical. to be able to use horizontal scroll you should use `scrollDirection` to `Axis.horizontal`. and your crashing issue is related to that you are adding `ListView` inside `ListView.builder` but you can use `Row` and horizontally scrolling instead:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: _users == null || _users!.isEmpty
      ? const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
      : Row(
          children: _users.map((user) => Card(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(user.name.toString()),
                  ListView.builder(
                    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    primary: false,
                    itemCount: user.chart.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int j) {
                      return Text(user.chart[j].ch_timestamp);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ).toList(),
        ),
);
```

happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your inner `ListView` with a `SizedBox` that has `width` specified.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 200,
  child: ListView.builder(
    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    primary: false,
    itemCount: _users[i].chart.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int j) {
      return Text(_users[i]
          .chart[j]
          .ch_timestamp); // display username as an example
    },
  ),
),
```

The problem here is your inner vertical `ListView` tries to take all the available `width` which is not possible because the parent `ListView` scrolls horizontally, which means it has infinite `width`.